# Converting shapefiles and geoJson to TopoJson and/or using geo2topo

Tags: node.js, d3.js, topojson

I'm a complete newb to Node.js.  I have not been able to use TopoJson to convert my geoJson file to TopoJson format.   I have topojson v3.0.0

I've written a test.js file that I'm executing with node.exe.

It's like the following:

```
var tjson = require("topojson")

tjson.topojson -p --no-stitch-poles -o zip3.topo.json -- zip3.geo.json

console.log("hello")
```

It complains about the no-stitch parameter.   But I tried a lot of things and now I suspect I'm missing something huge.  I looked over the github and now I am fairly sure that the process to convert geo to topo changed at some point.  Like maybe he split out the functionality to subsections?  I'm not sure.

Any help for a node newbie?

I started very confused about whether to launch things from the cmd prompt, within node, or to create a js file and launch that file with node.  I still don't know to do.  I got the best results by creating a js file and launching that js with node.exe.  But I still seem to be missing something.

I tried console.log(tjson)   and that showed me the list of functions for topojson.  But I don't know how to launch those functions.  I have tried to follow some tutorials for node but they dont seem to apply to TopoJson.

Thanks for the great tool and your help in advance.

I've always looked at his tutorial on using geo2topo.
https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c

https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-3-1158e4c55a1e

I get geo2topo is undefined.  I can only guess that the tutorial is making some kind of assumption that I know what environment to run these commands in and from what folder.

Answer (score 1):

To use it within a nodejs script/app, you need `topojson-server` package instead, along with `d3-geo-projection` package (to manipulate projections), so go on and install them:

```
npm install d3-geo-projection topojson-server
```

Now on your .js file we will need to read the file and transform it, then we can write it to an other file (Please note that the following code uses goeStitch projection, you can ofc use your wanted projection or omit it, also verify the path as the code uses static paths)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const geostitch = require('d3-geo-projection').geoStitch
const topojson = require('topojson-server')

// read the file
fs.readFile('./zip3.geo.json', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, data) => {
  // Treat read exception if any
  if (err)
    return console.error(err)

  // Convert to topo
  const topoData = topojson.topology(geostitch(data))

  // Now `topoData` contains the topojson we can proceed into saving it into a file
  fs.writeFile('zip3.topo.json', topoData, err => {
    if (err)
      return console.error(err)
    return console.log('GeoJson converted to TopoJson, successfully saved at `zip3.topo.json`') 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All code examples in the map tutorial are command-line snippets, nothing like `var tjson = require("topojson")` there. If you just stick to mike‘s examples and launch them from CLI you should be fine.

`geo2topo` is part of [topojson](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) which you install as a global node package with `npm install -g topojson`, as written.

Mike‘s examples are using a MacOS (i.e. unixoid) CLI, as am I with Linux - so you might need to slightly modify syntax to make it work on Windows or to add executables to your path environement variable. But that‘s beyond my knowledge. Maybe nodejs documentation is a starting point here!?